# Knowing what button is pressed in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there was a way I could ask if a certain button was pushed so that it would do a certain thing in the function.  I know I could split this up into two separate functions, but I want to know how to do this this way.

I'll put my code below.

```
function displaySort(form) {
    var list = form.values.value.replace(/\s+/g, '')
    list = list.split(/,/)
    if (document.getElementById("fSort").form.input.id) {
        list.sort()        
        var listAsString = list.join(", ")
        form.sortedDisplay.value = listAsString
    } else if (document.getElementById("rSort").form.input.id) {
        list.sort(reverseCompare)
        var listAsString = list.join(", ")
        form.reverseSortedDisplay.value = listAsString
    }
    window.alert("Messed Up"); 
}

function reverseCompare(s1, s2) {
    if (s1 < s2) {
        return +1
    } else if ( s1 == s2 ){
        return 0
    } else {
        return -1
    }
}
```

the form:

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="values" value="   Bob,  Ted,  Carol,           
                Bette, Alice,  Peter   "
                onclick="if (this.value == this.defaultValue) this.value=''"
                size="80"
                />
                <input type="button"
                onclick="displaySort(this.form)"
                value="Sort"
                id="fSort"
                />
                <input type="button"
                onclick="displaySort(this.form)"
                value="Reverse Sort"
                id="rSort"
                />
                <input type="reset"
                value="Reset Form"
                />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="sortedDisplay" value="Sorted list will show here"
                size="35"
                readonly
                style="font-size:24pt;font-weight:normal;"
                />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="reverseSortedDisplay" 
                value="Reverse sorted list will show here"
                size="35"
                readonly
                style="font-size:24pt;font-weight:normal;"
                />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: how is the function called?

Comment: You're asking for a button press, but I don't see any binding for `keyup`, `keydown`, `keypress` or alike. is that what you're looking to bind to?

Comment: @dfsq thanks for fixing it I was having trouble.

Comment: I'm looking for a input button Id to be clicked.  if fSort is then I do forward if rSort is then I do reverse sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another parameter to the function button:

```
function displaySort(form, button)
{ ...
```

And pass the button reference to it when clicked:

```
<input type="button"
   onclick="displaySort(this.form, this)"
   value="Reverse Sort"
   id="rSort"
/>
```

Comment: what do I call in the if statement to see if it is true? i tried button == document.getElementById("fSort").form.input.id  I tried making a var button = button;

Comment: just check button.id. You could also pass the id in directly: `onclick="displaySort(this.form, this.id)"`, or even pass a boolean in: `onclick="displaySort(this.form, true)"` and `onclick="displaySort(this.form, false)"`